# json.Marshal un-promoted field gets left out

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature, but json.Marshal leaves out fields not promoted because the upper-level already has the field.

Eg.

```
type Message struct {
    Type string
    Transaction
}

type Transaction struct {
    Type string
}
```

```
    m := &Message{
        Type: "mType",
        Transaction: Transaction{
            Type: "txType",
        },
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", m)

    j, _ := json.Marshal(m)
    fmt.Println(string(j))
```

obviously the child "Type" field does not get promoted because Message.Type is already there. But this prints:

```
&{Type:mType Transaction:{Type:txType}}
{"Type":"mType"}
```

**is json.Marshal leaving out the nested field on purpose?**

Answer (score 0):

Both `Type` fields would be marshaled to JSON as `Type` field name, and a JSON object cannot contain repeated keys. If you add json tags to the struct and name the fields differently, the unmashaler can construct a valid JSON object, and it can marshal both fields.